# Prove Two Topologies Equivalent

Tags: general-topology

I was reading Lawson's Topology as review and stumbled across this:

> For $X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, show that the usual topology on $X$ is the same as the subspace topology.

Here the usual topology is meant to be the metric topology composed of open balls. However, I fail to see how this is true. If $X$ consisted of a single point in $\mathbb{R}^n$ then the subspace topology on $X$ would be the trivial topology, which would not agree with the metric topology on $X$. This should hold true for any $X$ which is a finite point set. Am I thinking about something incorrectly?

Comment: If $X$ consisted of single point $a$, its topology is metric, $d(a,a)=0$. And if $X$ is finite its topology is also metric: $d(x,y)=1$ if $x\neq y$ and $d(x,x)=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your "counterexample" doesn't work. Take the $\epsilon$-ball with $\epsilon=1$ about your single point space, $X=\{p\}$. Then $B_1(p) = \{ x \in X \;|\; d(x,p)<1 \} = \{p\}$ (since $d(p,p)=0<1$). Therefore, $\{ p \}$ is open. Just as in the subspace topology.

So why do the subspace topology and the "usual" topology match? It essentially boils down to this: [I'll let $B$ denote balls in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $B'$ denote balls in $X$.]

$$B_\epsilon(x) \cap X = \{ y\in \mathbb{R}^n \;|\; d(y,x)<\epsilon \} \cap X = \{ y \in X \;|\; d(y,x) < \epsilon \} = B'_\epsilon(x)$$

So open balls in $X$ are exactly open balls in $\mathbb{R}^n$ intersected with $X$.

Therefore, since both the subspace topology and the "usual" topology share a common base, they must be equal.

Comment: So is this true for any metric space or just for those which embedd in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Yes. There's nothing special about $\mathbb{R}^n$ here. Showing that "the subspace topology and the topology induced by restricting the metric to a subspace are equal" is exercise #1 in section 21 of Munkres' Topology. :)